# How to extract top features by CATScore in r?

Tags: r, feature-selection

I am running a machine learning algorithm that uses CAT score for feature selection as

```
library(sda)
train1<- data.matrix(train, rownames.force = NA)
ranking.LDA = sda.ranking(train1[,1:lengthvar], train1[,lengthtrain], diagonal=FALSE)
topfs<-which(ranking.LDA[,"score"] >2)
```

My question is how to ask the CAT score to give me for example top 20 features? The only way I could extract features was setting a threshold, but this way, it gives me various number of features for different data set. What I want is always having eg. top 20 (or any other number) features.

Thanks in advance for your valuable contribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ranking.LDA gives a list of numbers.Hence we use a list function.

```
#As ranking.LDA gives a ranking of predictors we directly extract column names using this ranking.
colnames(train1[,ranking.LDA[1:20]])
```